# iPhone: View Photo Location in Maps

Tags: iphone, ios, photos, maps

I though this would be so obvious that the answer should be simple.

I have a photo taken somewhere. I select it in the Photos app, and select the Share icon. I would simply like the option to view the location of this photo in the Apple Map.

I have installed ViewEXIF, which does the job, but does too much, and takes an extra step to get to the Maps App.

Is there an extension which would do this job simply?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a map view built into iOS 9. Go to the photos tab and select the location at the top of the photos area! [image: You would select "Iceland"]

Comment: You can also go right back to the Years and then click on the location to see all the photos on a map for that year. That helps a lot if you have masses of moments to go through.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no iOS photos.app extension like this. I'd pay for one.

The method you are using (metadata display app) is the only way to do this. The Collections location display method doesn't work if you are working with images in the context of an album.

The Location feature in Google Photos.app is more capable but is likewise not readily available for a single selected image.